# Validate to staff_user : Django Restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want only staff_user can add product and can add maximum up to 10 products.

I'm probably new to django. I have tried something like below, but i have no idea about how to validate to the staff_user that he can add up to 10 products maximum.

It would be great if anybody could help me what i'm trying to solve is. thank you so much in advance.

models.py

```
class Cuboid(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    length = models.ForeignKey('FilterLength', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on= models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

serializers.py

```
class CuboidCreateSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cuboid
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
class CuboidCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Cuboid
    queryset = Cuboid.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CuboidCreateSerializers
    permission_classes = [IsStaff]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [***field-level validation of DRF***](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#field-level-validation)

```
class CuboidCreateSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_created_by(self, created_by):
        max_count = 10
        created_count = Cuboid.objects.filter(created_by=self.context['request'].user).count()
        if created_count >= max_count:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User allowed to create maximum of %s items" % max_count)
        return created_by

    class Meta:
        model = Cuboid
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: what if i want to validate to `staff_user` that he can add up to 10 products per `week` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in the documentation that outlines this:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

> IsAdminUser
> The IsAdminUser permission class will deny permission to any user, unless user.is_staff is True in which case permission will be allowed.

Based on this, I believe you have to check for two things, isAuthenticated and user.is_staff both have to be true. It may be that is_staff already accounts for isAuthenticated.